# How to delete signature from a PDF

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

[image]

This PDF has an invalid signature, so I want to delete it. Is there some tools to do it? I use Windows/Linux system.

PDF source: https://zh.z-library.se/book/3355492/93d409/classical-mechanics.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add a reference to the source of the pictured document into your question

Comment: Does this help https://codesteps.com/2014/01/13/how-to-resolve-at-least-one-signature-has-problems-error-in-adobe-reader/ . Please add a screenshot of the `Show Signer's Certificate` contents.

Comment: https://zh.z-library.se/book/3355492/93d409/classical-mechanics.html @jsotola

Comment: @Samveen I click `Show Signer's Certificate` but nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, which can let it do not display signature:

[image]

click the `Standards` button on the left side, and click:

`Remove Preflight Audit Trail` >> `Open Preflight` >> `Verify Preflight Certificate` >> `Edit`

It will show this panel:

[image]

**For all items** with `Error` (the red cross), click in and see `Custom checks in this profile`, unclick the `Enable check`.

[image]

At last you can save your PDF so that there will be no `At least one signature is invalid` warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Removed from that version via PDF hex editor (after working decompression) However it will be a "one off" exercise as based on human experience so not easy to program.

[image]

Start with faulty file. Decompress with any PDF decompressor as it would be in a PDF Reader/Editor. Check if not possible to add trust this signature.
Verified it cannot be trusted, so reasonable to correct it, by remove an invalid signature.

[image]

1. Determine signature entry point `<</Type/Annot/FT/Sig/MK<<>>` and remove it (but not before noting all the other chained addresses) so set that object number to `f`
2. For parent object remove linked /Annots
   `<</Type/Page/Annots 3330 0 R/Contents 3162 0 R/Cr....`
   `<</Type/Page                /Contents 3162 0 R/Cr..`
3. Note 3330 is chained to 3306 so set both objects to `f`
4. Humanly observe double entry of signings (possible cause of the failings) So follow chain to neuter object 3362 and both signature objects.
5. Check the file is not damaged and now valid PDF. So show as above no signatures and can be optionally re-signed afresh with anybody else's signature.
6. Optionally recompress with remove all the cleaned faults.

   before # objects = /Size 4976
   after # objects  = /Size 4950

The decompressors will do it different ways. So for above example  PDFTK uncompressed, will show starting # of objects in trailer as /Size 4955 (thus has done some housekeeping) AND initial target we seek as

```
2801 0 obj  << /MK  << >> /P 1549 0 R /Subtype /Widget /V 4007 0 R /T (Enfocus Preflight) /Type /Annot /Rect [-10 -10 -10 -10] /FT /Sig >> endobj
```

Parent is `/P 1549 0 R`

```
1549 0 obj ....../Parent 67 0 R /Contents 2256 0 R /Annots 2257 0 R /Type /Page...
```

needs changing to  remove that /Annot widget Ref

```
1549 0 obj ....../Parent 67 0 R /Contents 2256 0 R                  /Type /Page...
```

We now need to start tracking each objects numeric positions for later. So go to 2275 and note its **decimal** address in the hex edit.

**Epitaph to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Goldstein**

There are [editorial errors remaining in that Work](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003AmJPh..71..103T/abstract) so It would simply be best to wait for a posthumous 4th Edition from the same or alternate source.

Comment: what PDF decompressor do yo use? I tried qpdf from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17220/how-to-view-and-edit-the-code-of-a-pdf-file) but cannot find `<</Type/Annot/FT/Sig/MK<<>>`